# How to give class name to no results behavior in views

Tags: theming

I added price column first to view > hide it. I added special price column to view > in no results behavior i added price field token as below:

```
[field_price]
```

How to give a css class name to the 'no results behavior text'?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class to the no results token? Like
`<span class="some_class">[token]</span>`.
Dunno if it works that way. Try that.